# How can I specify a more appropriate font substitution?

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince

A particular PDF I have uses a non-embedded font named "TimesNRMT" that is not installed on my system. Instead of substituting the font with a similar one such as [Times New Roman](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ttf-mscorefonts-installer), Document Viewer is inappropriately choosing to use some sans-serif font, which makes the text nearly unreadable:

[image: screenshot]

How can I override this choice of font substitution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a rule in *your* `.fonts.conf` file. If it's not in your home folder, create it. Here's a full example of a `.fonts.conf` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any" >
      <string>TimesNRMT</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
      <string>Times New Roman</string>
    </edit>
  </match>

</fontconfig>
```

If you already have the file, just paste in the part enclosed by the match tags.

If you're using Font Manager the file is in a different place(~/.config/font-manager/local.conf).

Comment: Are you recommending that I just disregard the giant ***DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE*** warning at the top?

Comment: Not really, I've done similar substitutions in **my local** .fonts.conf. I'm editing my answer. Silly of me to think it's obvious which file I was talking about. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. I chose to use [`alias`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html#AEN190) to keep it simple. [`~/fonts.conf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/621807/).

Comment: In the latest versions of Ubuntu, you can also do this through the GUI if you are using font-manager. In the Font Manager app there's a button in the bottom left for font preferences, and this brings up a menu which has "Alias Editor". You can edit font aliases in there. This gets written out to ~/.config/font-manager/conf.d/XX-aliases.conf.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you’ll need to install MS Core Fonts.

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Comment: A better option would be to install Red Hat's Liberation fonts, which are near equivalents of popular Microsoft fonts, and substitute them as susggested by miloshadzic.

Comment: Better to use the real thing, as ‘near equivalents’ don't cut it in publishing.